# Has anyone an example of a linear contin. operator T of a Hilbert space on C with a residual spectral value c for which T-c.Id has unbounded inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Let H be a complex Hilbert space (with infinite dimension - best countable, in which case it will be isomorphic to $\ell^2$ and many other typical H. spaces), T a linear continuous operator on H having a non empty residual spectrum $S_r$. I would like to receive an example where there is at least one number c in $S_r$ for which T-c.Id (Id=identity map) has a non continuous (equiv. unbounded) inverse. Thanks

Comment: This isn't possible by the [bounded inverse theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem).

Comment: Theo, I don't think so. In the intro of that wikipedia                                                                                                           article, It says that "a bijective bounded linear operator T from one Banach space to another has bounded inverse" which is not applicable when the image of T is not closed (because not complete then, so not a Banach space) BTW if c were in the continuous spectrum, it is exactly what happens: then T-c.Id has never a continuous inverse

Comment: If you want an operator on a Hilbert space $H$ with an inverse map, then the map must be surjective, i.e. the image must be the whole space $H$. This image is closed in $H$. You can't have an inverse operator and not have a closed image. If this is not what you mean by "inverse", you should specify what you mean in the question.

Comment: From the context it should be clear that by "inverse" I don't mean here an inverse in the algebra of continuous linear operators of H - which exists only for bijective operators H -> H. it's a bit a simple word to mean the inverse of an injective operator T considered as a bijective map H -> T(H). This exists for T-c.I not only when c is out of the (total) spectrum of T (then we have an inverse in said algebra) but also when c is in the spectrum but not in the point spectrum of T in other words for c in the continuous or residual spectrum. BTW I found now an example myself. See below later

Comment: I don't think it is clear from context. I'd say there's very little context in the question. In fact, context is generally considered [a requirement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) for posting here. This question demonstrates why this is so: you asked a question assuming a slightly less conventional definition of "inverse" (or perhaps, "operator"), which, even though it is standard in certain fields, it's not universal. But, we are not mind-readers here! It may be unambiguous in your mind, but it's not in ours'.

Comment: In future, you should endeavour to make the question self-contained and clear. If you are using terms in slightly different ways to the mainstream, then make sure to define them. Also, please include your own attempts to solve the problem; the more you tell us about this, the less likely a miscommunication like this will occur. Finally, you should also format with Latex, to make your questions more readable.

Comment: Not sure mainstream in this is the way you think. Often there is >1 mainstream - see e.g. measure theory! For LaTeX: it may be no problem for your generation, mine is the one born during WW2 (in CH) ... I just decided to try to use LaTeX, it's not easy. The makers of SW for it seem not to be mainly interested in math. - despite the importance of math. for that of  LaTeX - nor do they seem to be much educated in math. ... my test with a double sum shows a bad looking result. Question to you: How can I look at the source code of passages in this site using LaTeX?

Comment: I do appreciate that learning LaTeX is no trivial ask, even for someone in my generation. You can view the LaTeX source for a question or answer by pressing "edit" or "improve this question/answer" and look at the code (nothing will change or break until you press the "Save Edit" button, but you will get to play around with the code and see what happens in real time). You can also right-click on any formula anywhere on the site, and click on Show Math As $\to$ TeX Commands (though you'll need to surround such code in `$` or `$$` signs.

Comment: We also have a formatting tutorial/quick reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Read the body first, and you can look at answers to get pointers as to how to do more complicated formatting.

Comment: Thanks for these indications, which helped me among others things to understand the role of the dollar signs - single and double - in LaTeX insertion. But it didn't help for my problem with double sums; this I found finally in the help for wikipedia editors that need it in math. articles. Too bad that this is apparently useless for my LyX software which I installed because it has WYSIWYG (more precisely WYSIWYM what you see is what you MEAN). I adapted things in my other question beginning with "For which values"; you might look there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose H is a Hilbert space of infinite countable Hilbert dimension, $\displaystyle(e_n)_{n \scriptstyle \in \mathbb N}$ a Hilbert base of H, T and U are continuous injective but not surjective operators of H with T(H) closed and U(H) dense (in H). For example, we can use T = the right shift on said base, and U = S-c.I where S=T or S = the left shift on the same base, c is any complex nb. such that |c|=1 (especially c=1 or c=-1 are simplest cases) ... it is well known that c is in the continuous spectrum of S, showing that this choice for U is OK. Now consider the operator W=TU. W is continuous, injective and W(H) = T(U(H)). Since T is a topological vector spaces isomorphism (in fact even of Banach spaces in my example) H -> T(H), the fact that U(H) is dense in H and not= H carries over to: T(U(H)) is dense in T(H) and not= T(H). This implies that W(H) is 1° not dense in H (being contained in a proper closed subspace) 2° not closed in H (since it is not closed in T(H) ). This result can be interpreted like this: W has z=0 in its residual spectrum with the inverse of W-z.I (=W) *not* continuous